# onChange validation for submit

Tags: javascript, html

For a field I have validation for onChange() event. When I change the field and click on submit button. Does the onChange() events checks the validation.

In my case it is not checking.

Any help or suggestions please

```
<textarea id='abc' name='abc' onChange="checkvalidation('abc','true')>ddd</textarea>

function checkvalidation(field, numericOrNot){
var Value = '#' + field;
    var fieldval = $(field).val();
    if(numericOrNot) {
        if(isNaN(fieldval)) {
            alert("not a number");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery? Also, tapping into `onchange` to revert the value in the textarea to its previous value is not going to work. You'll have to tap into the `keydown` event.

Answer (score 1):

The onChange event should fire when you've changed the value of a form field and remove focus from that field. It should fire before you click the submit button.

However, you're missing a closing quote after the `)` in your html.

```
<textarea id='abc' name='abc' onChange="checkvalidation('abc','true')">ddd</textarea>
//-------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Here's how to change your code so that it uses a `data-` attribute to determine the data type.

**Html**

```
<textarea id='abc' name='abc' data-type="number">ddd</textarea>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$("#abc").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.data("type") == "number") {
    if(isNaN($this.val())) {
      alert("not a number");
    }
  }
});
```

**Example on how to run this code when the form is submitted**

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  var $this = $("#abc");
  if($this.data("type") == "number") {
    if(isNaN($this.val())) {
      alert("not a number");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can someone help me how to use jquery.data() to bind the 'true' value and check on submit

Comment: so the above code only works when we change the value  not while submiting the form right?

Comment: That is correct. If I were you, I would abandon this effort and use a validation plugin like: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Can we do something to this code to do validation while submiting the form

Comment: Ok I added another example on how to use it onSubmit. But for goodness sake! You really need to write your question with ALL the relevant information upfront.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. But my problem is I am creating the textareas on the fly and some are numeric fields and some are string. For that situation while submiting the form I need a validation.